# Vue.js: Binding a function to Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I can't really explain this in words, but I want to bind my screen height to a calculated value. The code here does not work, so I'd like to know how to make it work.

```
<template>
    <b-container id="notfound-container">
        <b-row align-v="center" v-bind:style="{ height : h + 'px' }">
            <b-col style="align-items:center">
                <h1>404 Error</h1>
                <p>The page you have requested does not exist.</p>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'tHome',
        data () {
            return {
                h: (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('notfound-container').getBoundingClientRect().top)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
    h1, h2 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    a {
        color: #42b983;
    }
</style>
```

The value does not need to be dynamically updated, but I'd like it to be calculated at least once.
Currently, I get the error that "h" is not initialized.

Comment: It seems strange to get that error, as it works here https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/8/ maybe check if you have a div `notfound-container` div or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` properties are evaluated before the DOM  is rendered. So perform your calculation logic after the DOM is mounted , i.e inside the `mounted()` lifecycle hook

```
data(){
    h: null
},
mounted(){
       this.h = (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('notfound-container').getBoundingClientRect().top);
}
```

EDIT:

You can add an event listener for wimdow resize in the `mounted()` hook itself:

```
data(){
    h: null
},
mounted(){
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.setHeight);
},
beforeDestroy(){
    //remove the resize listener
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setHeight);
},
methods:{
    setHeight(){
        this.h = (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('notfound-container').getBoundingClientRect().top);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know this actually. Is this described in the doc or did you get that from the vue lifecycles chart?

Comment: @samayo it is explained in the API section for lifecycle hooks: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: This is very good to know. How can I make it update whenever window.innerHeight changes? Or, even better, every tick?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.